# Understanding mutability in Python

Tags: python, mutability

I have this snippet:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b = [4,5,6] # a doesnt change
```

and this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b[0] = 5 # a also changes
```

How is `b`'s initialization playing a part in deciding the mutability of `a`?

Comment: When I execute the last block a doesn't change. Which is exactly the behavior one would expect (and hope for ...).

Comment: To check whether variable pointing to memory address, use id() function. In your case - initially id(a) and id(b) is same. After executing b = [4,5,6], id(b) changes. So, 'b' is pointing to different memory address and 'a' remains same. Simillarly test your second script.

Comment: I used the wrong second snippet. Corrected it.

Comment: Read [Drastically Improve Your Python: Understanding Python's Execution Model](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a list and assign it to a variable, like

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

You create an object, and the variable a holds a reference to that object. When you do

```
b = a
```

You assign the same reference in b, so now both a and b point to your list. So when you execute

```
b[0] = 5
```

You alter that same list.

You can see this in action by using the id() function, which returns the memory address of the object:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> id(a), id(b)
(140454191340720, 140454191340720)
```

They are identical. The point is, a and b are not lists themselves, they point to a list.

When you do something like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b = [2, 3, 4]
```

You first assigned to b a reference to the list that a points to, but then you assign a new reference to it.

By the way, this can bite you in the behind when you do something along the lines of

```
def foo (a=[]):
    a.append(42)
    return a
```

since the argument a points to the same list on every invocation, if you call this function 5 times without arguments, the list will contain 5x 42:

```
foo(); foo(); foo(); foo();
print(foo())
>>> [42, 42, 42, 42]
```